# Find correct difference for CLLocation course between two coordinates

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am trying to keep track of the change in course values of CLLocation objects.

The issue is, lets say user is moving 0 deg. due north and then goes 350 deg.

Now I don't know whether user taken a full circular turn (350 - 0 = 350) or just a 10 degree turn. Does CLLocation object provides this info?

Comment: You're going to need to use `CoreMotion` to access the gyros for that.

Comment: Any article or research paper you can point me to? I can't seem to find one. People are either using magnetometer but in that case they say it is affected by the Magnetic fields of other electronic devices inside the car.